# ListView setOnItemClickListener action for specific item

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, I have a ListView with different items. The issue that I am having is that I want to perform listeners or actions to each specific item. Right now, the code I have when you press an item, it applies it to all items instead of an item specifically.

What I am trying to do is stream videos when a specific item is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViedoStream viedoStream_data[] = new ViedoStream[]
    {
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image0, "Mission TV"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image1, "HCBN Philippines"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image2, "Global Family Network"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image3, "2CBN"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image4, "Red ADvenir"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image5, "Alfa Television"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image6, "Light Channel Hungary"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image7, "Light Channel Rumania"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image8, "Light Channel Germany"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image9, "Terceiro Anjo"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image10, "HCBN Indonesia"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image11, "TV Famille")
    };

    ViedoStreamAdapter adapter = new ViedoStreamAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, viedoStream_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

    //  Place code here with the action: RIGHT NOW I HAVE A TOAST FOR EXAMPLE ONLY

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TV Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
   });

}}
```

As you can see, when an item is selected, the toast applies to every single item on the ListView. Please note the the Toast is just an example I am using. I want to stream http videos instead. Now, how can I do this so that every time I select an item, it only does an action for that specific item?

I do programing for iPhone and I am new to all this... In iPhone, this is how I do it. *This is just an example of how the logic looks like:

```
if (item == @"TV Item" { 
  //Do Action
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnItemClickListener()` applies to all the `ListView's` Items by design, If you wish to pass the control to specific `Widgets`, then you set to them their individual `OnClickListener()` methods. This needs to be done in the `Adapter`. In your case, the `ViedoStreamAdapter`.

Consider this as an example. In an app of mine, I use the `OnItemClickListener()` for showing the Tweet details in a separate Activity. That works fine. But when a user clicks the `ImageView` in the same item, I need to show that Twitter Profile. So, in the `Activity`, I use the `OnItemClickListener()` and in the adapter, I override the `ImageView's` `OnClickListener()`. Like this:

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
holder.imgvwProfilePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(activity, ProfileContainer.class);
        profileIntent.putExtra("userId", arrTweets.get(position).getAuthorID());
        profileIntent.putExtra("userScreenName", arrTweets.get(position).getScreenName());
        activity.startActivity(profileIntent);

    }
});
```

In this case, I have an `ArrayAdapter<TimeLineData> arrTweets`. And `TimeLineData` is a POJO class that is a `setter and getter` for individual values.

If you do not need the `OnItemClickListener()`, feel free to remove it. It does not affect the `OnClickListener()` that you setup in the `Adapter`.

When the `ImageView` is clicked, I pull out the data for the current position using this: `arrTweets.get(position).getAuthorID()`. And the `position` is the one in the `getView()` of the `Adapter`.

Do ask if you have more questions on this.

**NOTE:** This should be done before your return the `View` instance in your `getView()`. For instance, the code above is called before this in my app:

```
return vi;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As pointed out by the OP in the comments, this is what worked for him:

```
if(position == 0){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am starting to understand a little now ;) Is it possible that you can explain me how to perform this with an if statement? Because I will be using http video stream code and I have no clue how I will change the url of each video according to its specific station.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz: Sure. I would be happy to help. :-) Let me update my post with a few specifics. Also, it would help if you were to post your `Adapter` code in your question too. That would help a lot too.

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to do this: if(position == 0){ } position is a int so I can simply make a couple of this if statements and I am golden :) Thanks for the help! If you want, add this code so that I can mark it as an answer and other people can see it.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz: I am glad I could be of help. :-)